# Issue comparing UIColors in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor

I need to compare two UIColors, but for some reason it always return false. I tried to compare using `==` and `.isEqual()`, but neither of them seem to work.

```
//This is a sample of the colors I have created
let blue_color = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 180/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1)


//This is the SpriteNode I have to compare

let square = SKSpriteNode(color: randomColorController(), size: ksquaresize)
```

randomColorController() is just a function that randomizes colors and returns it, so it is called when square is created.

```
func randomColorController() -> UIColor {
    let random = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1

    switch random {
    case 1:
        let color = blue_color
        return color
    case 2:
        let color = yellow_color
        return color
    case 3:
        let color = yellow_color
        return color
    default:
        let color = UIColor.clearColor()
        return color
    }
```

Then, depending on the position of the square I have created it will check collision comparing the color of the square I have created and the colors I have initialized at the beginning.

```
func checkCollision(currentTime: CFTimeInterval, Square: SKSpriteNode) -> Int{
    let color = Square.color

    print(color.isEqual(blue_color))
    print(color.isEqual(red_color))
    print(color.isEqual(yellow_color))

    if Square.position.y >= 0 && Square.position.y <= 40 {
        if color.isEqual(blue_color) && (Square.position.x < basesize.width) {
                // ADDS 1 POINT TO THE SCORE LABEL
                flag = 1
                points += 1
            } else if color.isEqual(red_color) && (Square.position.x > (basesize.width*2)){
                flag = 1
                points += 1
            } else if color.isEqual(yellow_color) && (Square.position.x < (basesize.width*2)) &&  (Square.position.x > basesize.width) {
                flag = 1
                points += 1
            } else {
                flag = -1
            }
    }
```

But `color.isEqual(blue_color)` or any of the other colors, doesn't seem to work. I have printed `Square.color` and `blue_color` (and the others), and they match. But it would always return `false`.

Comment: You need to make sure the colors are in the same color space/model. If they are not, they will not be equal. Try converting the colors first to make sure they are in the same color space.

Comment: What do you mean converting colors? If they're within the same class, aren't they in the same space? And since Im using the same variable to set the colors and compare later, aren't they the same?

Comment: Does Swift have the same issue with integer division that Objective-C has? In other words - does `122/255` give `0` or the desired `0.47843`?

Comment: It gives the right value. 122/255 = 0.47843. I have tested this a bunch of times in Square.color and my initialized colors.

Comment: Here is some info on color space don't know if it will help. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_color/dq_color.html

Comment: I just made checkCollision outputs the Square.color, blue_color, yellow_color and red_color values:

`Square Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.992157 0.835294 0.482353 1  
Blue Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.478431 0.705882 0.745098 1  
Yellow Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.992157 0.835294 0.482353 1  
Red Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.933333 0.454902 0.278431 1`

Comment: I have modified that already, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "==" or isEqual. I have just tested both of them and they work fine:

```
let redColor = UIColor.redColor()
let greenColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let blueColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let testColor = UIColor.greenColor()


println( testColor == redColor )    //  false
println( testColor == greenColor )  // true
println( testColor == blueColor )   // false

println( testColor.isEqual(redColor) )    //  false
println( testColor.isEqual(greenColor) )  // true
println( testColor.isEqual(blueColor) )   // false
```

I have just reproduced the issue only happens after extracting the SKSpriteNode color and as you said only with fraction colors. You can work your way around this issue comparing the color description as follow:

```
let blue_color = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 180/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1)
let yellow_color = UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 213/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1)
let red_color = UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 116/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 1)

func randomColorController() -> UIColor {
    let random = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1

    switch random {
    case 1:
        return blue_color
    case 2:
        return red_color
    case 3:
        return yellow_color
    default:
        return UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}



let square = SKSpriteNode(color: randomColorController(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

if square.color.description ==  blue_color.description {
    println(true)
}
if square.color.description == red_color.description {
    println(true)
}
if square.color.description == yellow_color.description {
    println(true)
}
```

Comment: I've started with built-in colors, and it was working perfectly. But then I wanted to change to custom colors, and that's when the issue started happening.

Comment: I have just reproduced the issue only happens after extracting the SKSpriteNode color and as you said only with fraction colors

Comment: Do you have any ideia on how to fix it, Leo?

Comment: Yes I have just found out. You can compare the color description

Comment: It works perfectly for the blue square, but for the yellow and red ones it doesn't. I changed it from `square.color == red_color` to `square.color.description == red_color.description`, and it also didn't work. That's funny.

Comment: Can you post the other colors? your switch was wrong

Comment: I realized my switch was wrong, but even after changing it didn't work. 

There are the colors:
    `let blue_color = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 180/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1)`
     let yellow_color = UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 213/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1)
   let red_color = UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 116/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 1)`

Comment: I have changed the statement to `Square.color.description.isEqual(red_color.description)` and it worked once every time I build it, but then it stopped

Comment: It works fine here for all the colors. now your issue is somewhere else. try using my code with playground you will see it works for all of them

Comment: I just decided to create another function to treat the problematic else statement, and it works perfectly now. Thank you, Leo!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
extension UIColor {
    func isEqual(color: UIColor?) -> Bool {
        guard let color = color else { return false }

        var red:CGFloat   = 0
        var green:CGFloat = 0
        var blue:CGFloat  = 0
        var alpha:CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        var targetRed:CGFloat   = 0
        var targetGreen:CGFloat = 0
        var targetBlue:CGFloat  = 0
        var targetAlpha:CGFloat = 0
        color.getRed(&targetRed, green: &targetGreen, blue: &targetBlue, alpha: &targetAlpha)

        return (Int(red*255.0) == Int(targetRed*255.0) && Int(green*255.0) == Int(targetGreen*255.0) && Int(blue*255.0) == Int(targetBlue*255.0) && alpha == targetAlpha)
    }
}
```

I tested in swift 3, 4